# Dataset Association of Association vs Hierarchical data

Tags: dataset

I have the following dataset:

```
Dataset[
 <|1 -> <|"High School" -> 96, "Graduate" -> 138, "Uneducated" -> 58, 
"College" -> 53, "Unknown" -> 75, "Post-Graduate" -> 41, 
"Doctorate" -> 1|>, 
2 -> <|"Uneducated" -> 185, "Graduate" -> 382, "College" -> 130, 
 "High School" -> 265, "Unknown" -> 163, "Post-Graduate" -> 59, 
 "Doctorate" -> 57|>, 
3 -> <|"High School" -> 481, "Uneducated" -> 366, "Graduate" -> 784, 
"Unknown" -> 374, "Post-Graduate" -> 118, "College" -> 251, 
"Doctorate" -> 98|>, 
 4 -> <|"High School" -> 540, "Graduate" -> 866, 
"Post-Graduate" -> 161, "Doctorate" -> 152, "Unknown" -> 454, 
"College" -> 268, "Uneducated" -> 433|>, 
5 -> <|"Graduate" -> 628, "Unknown" -> 293, "College" -> 224, 
"Uneducated" -> 278, "Doctorate" -> 93, "High School" -> 402, 
"Post-Graduate" -> 91|>, 
6 -> <|"Graduate" -> 256, "High School" -> 181, "Doctorate" -> 39, 
"College" -> 67, "Unknown" -> 123, "Uneducated" -> 140, 
"Post-Graduate" -> 44|>, 
7 -> <|"Unknown" -> 37, "Doctorate" -> 11, "High School" -> 46, 
"Graduate" -> 74, "College" -> 20, "Uneducated" -> 27, 
"Post-Graduate" -> 2|>, 8 -> <|"High School" -> 2|>|>
]
```

According to my understanding of the `Dataset` documentation, this should be displayed as a table where the numerical categories are the rows and the educational categories the columns. Instead it's displayed as a hierarchical data (rows of rows). Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To obtain a tabular rendering for a dataset, all rows must have the same number of columns, with the same set of keys, in the same order.  But in our case the last association has fewer elements than the rest and the keys are in different orders in each row.  Assuming that `$ds` contains the dataset:

```
$ds[Values /* (PadRight[#, Automatic, ""] &), Keys]
```

[image]

To get a tabular rendering, we must normalize the key order and fill in the blanks in that last row.  `KeyUnion` will do this:

```
$ds[Keys[#] -> KeyUnion[Values[#]] & /* AssociationThread]
```

[image: resultant table]

This technique will also work when multiple rows are missing values:

```
$ds2 = $ds[All, RandomSample[#, RandomInteger[Length[#]]] &];
$ds2[Keys[#] -> KeyUnion[Values[#]] & /* AssociationThread]
```

[image: sparser table]

Comment: Interesting. I suspected that length could be an issue, so I tried `ds[KeyDrop[8]]` (where `ds` is the name I gave the dataset), but is still was not rendered as a table. What is the difference here?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Normal forms look the same between ```ds[KeyDrop[8]]``` and ```ds[KeyDrop[8]][KeyDrop[8]][Keys[#] -> KeyUnion[Values[#]] & /* AssociationThread]```, apart from order of keys. Can that be a factor?

Comment: Yes, the order of the keys is important.  `KeyUnion` will not only supply missing keys but also normalize the order.

Comment: That explains a lot!